# laravel 5.4 common arrays, constants, common functions?

Tags: php, laravel-5

laravel 5.4, where to put common arrays, constants, common functions, so that it is accessible every where eg. in controller, model, mailables, etc.
eg.
 $common_array = array("1" => "a", "2" => "b");

where to put above array, so that, it can be accessible everywhere just like configuration.

Answer (score 2):

you can create **helpers.php** in **app** directory and add it to composer autoload like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": ["app/helpers.php"]
},
```

now you can add variables, functions to helpers.php and it will be accessible from anywhere.

for example:

```
//helpers.php
$common_array = array("1" => "a", "2" => "b");

function global_func() {
    return 'test';
}
```

now both $common_array and global_func will be available in every controller, model, blade file.

you can name helpers.php anything you like.